# Macbook Ram Speed Question (1033 or 1333 MHZ)

Tags: xcode, memory, macbook-pro

I have two 4GB modules of ram for a Macbook Pro (1033MHZ).
I have a new Macbook pro that came with two 2GB modules (1333MHZ)

Would it be best if I left the 4GB faster ram in? Or would it really be noticeable if I swapped it for the 8GB of slower ram?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you plan on doing with the machine but 9.99 times out of 10 you're better off going with more ram (8gb in this case), especially for RAM-intensive applications such as databases, virtual machines, music/video/audio/photo editing.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to notice the difference.  I would take 8GB of 1033 over 4GB of 1333 any day and twice on Sunday.